# ctypes cdecl gives 4 bytes missing when calling gcc compiled dll returning a struct

Tags: python, windows, gcc, ctypes

I have a c library (chipmunk) that I want to call using ctypes. However, it fails on functions that return a struct?

The error I get is

```
File "qw.py", line 19, in <module>
b = cpBBNew3(1,2,3,4)
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

This is the (relevant) c-code:
in cpBB.h

```c
typedef struct cpBB {
    cpFloat l, b, r ,t;
} cpBB;
cpBB cpBBNew3(cpFloat l, cpFloat b, cpFloat r, cpFloat t);
```

in cpBB.c

```c
cpBB cpBBNew3(cpFloat l, cpFloat b, cpFloat r, cpFloat t) {
    cpBB bb = {l, b, r, t};
    return bb;
}
```

compiled with

> gcc -O3 -std=gnu99 -shared -c
>
> gcc -O3 -std=gnu99 -shared -s

Then the python looks like

```python
from ctypes import *

chipmunk_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('''C:/code/pymunk/trunk/pymunk/chipmunk.dll''')

class cpBB(Structure):
    pass
cpBB._pack_ = 4
cpBB._fields_ = [
    ('l', c_double),
    ('b', c_double),
    ('r', c_double),
    ('t', c_double),
]

cpBBNew3 = chipmunk_lib.cpBBNew3
cpBBNew3.restype = cpBB
cpBBNew3.argtypes = [c_double, c_double, c_double, c_double]

b = cpBBNew3(1,2,3,4)
```

This particular example works if I compile with -mrtd and use windll (using stdcall). However using stdcall on the whole library creates segmentation faults in other parts of the library when compiled with optimizations and a newish version of GCC which is why it would be nice to get cdecl working.

Comment: Note that if using stdcall and optimizations causes segmentation faults, there are probably bugs in your code that using cdecl is masking.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I asked about that error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902348/compiling-c-with-fomit-frame-pointer-mrtd-creates-segfault-on-free-function-po 
From the answer by duskwuff it seems like I shouldnt use stdcall meaning cdecl must be the way to go?

Comment: You have to call external functions using the call convention expected by that function, so if you need to have the same function pointer able to point to either an external (C library) function or an internal (your code) function, then, yes, you'll have to stick to cdecl.

Comment: (If you can't find a better solution, one workaround would be to change cpBBNew3 so that it takes a pointer to a structure as one of the arguments and returns void.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of struct and compiler/platform, cdecl may return structs by passing hidden pointer to caller-allocated struct before normal parameters. Try the following:

```
b = cpBB()
cpBBNew3(byref(b),1,2,3,4)
```