# Compiling c with -fomit-frame-pointer -mrtd creates segfault on free function pointer

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

This c code crash with a segmentation fault if I compile with GCC using -fomit-frame-pointer and -mrtd.

Is my code wrong in some way? Other function pointers works as expected, but not when its the free-function that is being passed? I get a warning when compiling, but I dont understand why or what I should do to fix. (I usually dont code in c, this error comes from a 3d part library that I use)

I need rtd/stdcall because Im on windows and need to call this library from python with ctypes, and -fomit-frame-pointer is included by default when compiling with GCC with -O1. (GCC version is 4.6.1 from TDM/Mingw32) It feels a bit strange that a default optimization option would cause trouble?

c-code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// void free ( void * ptr );
void test(void* o, void (*freeFunc)(void*)) {
    freeFunc(o);
}

int main() {
    int *p = (int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    test(p, free);
}
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mrtd -c fx.c
gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -mrtd fx.o -o fx.exe
```

compile warning:

```
fx.c: In function 'main':
fx.c:11:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'test' from incompatible pointer type[enabled by default]
fx.c:5:6: note: expected 'void (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(void *)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GCC manual page for `-mrtd`:

```
Warning: this calling convention is incompatible with the one
normally used on Unix, so you cannot use it if you need to call
libraries compiled with the Unix compiler.
```

The warning is kind of bizarre, but I believe it's simply trying to tell you that you're passing a pointer to a function which uses an incompatible calling convention. I imagine the `free` in libc would be such a function; I'm surprised that calling `calloc` works at all. (Or perhaps it isn't, and what you're seeing is a delayed failure!)

Comment: Ok, that make sense I guess. The reason for using -mrtd is that I need stdcall when calling this library from ctypes (python ffi lib). When using cdecl I get another error which I asked for help about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890577/ctypes-cdecl-gives-4-bytes-missing-when-calling-gcc-compiled-dll-returning-a-str And -fomit-frame-pointer comes from -O1 which include it by default.

Comment: But then I guess my question is what can be done about it? This means that I really shouldn't use anything from stdlib together with mrtd meaning its more or less out of the question to use mrtd on a full library if compiling with gcc?

Comment: Hmm. Actually, that text isn't from mingw GCC -- I'm not as familiar with that environment, and it might not apply there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resolve the problem, at least for this simple example, by declaring the function pointer properly using the [cdecl attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).  Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(void* o, void (__attribute__((cdecl))*freeFunc)(void*)) {
    freeFunc(o);
}

int main() {
    int *p = (int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    test(p, free);
}
```